# How to specify project entrypoint to gradle build

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, gradlew

In my flutter project when I run either :

```
./gradlew build
```

or

```
gradle build
```

I get this type of error :

```
.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:11:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': Le fichier sp├®cifi├® est introuvable.
```

This is because my main.dart is located in "lib/src/main" instead of "lib" , and it needs to stays that way.

When I run my build with flutter I use an option to specify the main location :

```
flutter build apk -t "lib/src/main/main.dart"
```

And it works fine.

Is there such option for./gradlew build or gradle build ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem here. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer...

```
./gradlew build -Ptarget=lib/entry_point_name.dart
```

The -P indicates gradle that what follows is a project parameter, in this case the parameter's name is 'target'. This parameter is used to override the default main.dart entry point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio then follow these steps:

1: Go to edit configurations[image]

2: Change the entry point [image]

Thats it.